# NSTextView always uses system language when hyphenating?

Tags: macos, nstextview, hyphenation

It seems to me that English texts will get better hyphenation if the system language in macOS is set to English. Thing is, it is hard to be sure, and restarting with a new system language is cumbersome, so I haven't tested this thoroughly, but I'm reasonable sure that I've only seen "somet-hing" and similar when my system was set to Swedish.

This is on macOS Big Sur, in an NSTextView with hyphenation switched on by setting hyphenationFactor to 1 on an NSParagraphStyle object in an NSAttributedString. It is not a web view. The application is not localized, so the app language is English even when the system is set to Swedish. Setting NSAccessibilityLanguageTextAttribute to "en-US" seems to have no effect.

I'd like to know if anyone can confirm this, and if so, can anything be done about it?

Comment: See the documentation of [hyphenationFactor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1535553-hyphenationfactor/), "This property detects the user-selected language by examining the first item in preferredLanguages.".

Comment: Thanks! I had missed that. So there is no way to change this undesirable behavior?

Comment: `NSAttributedString` reads the language from `NSUserDefaults` with key `NSHyphenationLanguage`. This is undocumented and may not work in every version of macOS.

Comment: Thanks again! That is better than nothing. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `hyphenationFactor`:

> This property detects the user-selected language by examining the first item in preferredLanguages.

`+[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` is called once from `-[NSAttributedString lineBreakByHyphenatingBeforeIndex:withinRange:]` but before that the language is read from `NSUserDefaults` with key `NSHyphenationLanguage`. Setting the language with

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:@"en" forKey:@"NSHyphenationLanguage"]
```

seems to work but it is undocumented, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Works like a charm! But how did you find out about this UserDefaults key?

Comment: @wakel I added some breakpoints here and there and watched what's happening.